# Openstreetmaps: Make my scale have 1cm in the paper

Tags: leaflet, openstreetmap

I got a complain from a client that said that the scale on the paper had 1.2 cm instead of 1 cm. I'm trying to fix this but I don't have much experience with `openstreetmaps` nor `leaflet` to know where do I need to change the code to make my scale have 1 cm all the time.

Can someone point me to the right direction? Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean your client prints the page, and wants the Scale Control bar to be 1cm long, and showing the equivalent distance as represented by the map?

Comment: Yes. I'm using PhantomJs for that. The client wants the Scale Control to be 1 cm yes because it's easier for doing the math I think

Answer (score 2):

1. Instead of the standard Leaflet Scale Control, you should write your own Control (or any other widget). The standard one does not have a fixed length: it adjusts it so that it can represent a "round" distance (like "1km", "50km", etc.). But it sounds like you want the reverse: have a fixed length, representing whatever distance.
2. You should check the pixel to length (on paper) ratio of your browser and printer. You should be able to adjust zoom / scale.